# Regex find and add

Tags: ruby, regex

I have `str = "1, 2, a, 3, 4, z"`

I want to use Regex to find and add .3 to the end of all the digits and a colon `:` to the beginning of all the characters. So the desired output would be:

```
"1.3, 2.3, :a, 3.3, 4.3, :z"
```

Can I do that with gsub in Ruby? Is that the most efficient way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) accepts optional block. The return value of the block is used as substitution string.

```
str = "1, 2, a, 3, 4, z"
str.gsub(/\d+|[a-z]+/i) { |x| x =~ /\d/ ? x + '.3' : ':' + x }
# => "1.3, 2.3, :a, 3.3, 4.3, :z"
```

using capturing group:

```
str.gsub(/(\d+)|([a-z]+)/i) { $1 ? $1 + '.3' : ':' + $2 }
# => "1.3, 2.3, :a, 3.3, 4.3, :z"
```

Comment: Downvoter: How can I improve the answer?

Comment: @falstru: no idea why you got downvoted. Your answer is better than Marek's imo.

Comment: I upvoted, but `x =~ /\d/` is redundant. You can improve the answer by using named capture.

Comment: @sawa, Thank you for advice. I added another version that use capturing group. Is that what you mean?

Comment: That is what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

From [String#gsub documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

> If replacement is a String it will be substituted for the matched
>   text. It may contain back-references to the pattern’s capture groups
>   of the form \d, where d is a group number, or \k, where n is a
>   group name. If it is a double-quoted string, both back-references must
>   be preceded by an additional backslash. However, within replacement
>   the special match variables, such as $&, will not refer to the current
>   match.

The solution:

```
str = "1, 2, a, 3, 4, z"
str.gsub(/(\d)+/, '\1.3').gsub(/([a-z])+/i, ':\1')
# => "1.3, 2.3, :a, 3.3, 4.3, :z"
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-regexp and gsub version:

```
str = "1, 2, a, 3, 4, z"

result = str.split(', ').map do |chr|
  case chr.downcase
    when 'a'..'z' then  ":#{chr}"
    when '1'..'9' then  "#{chr}.3"
  end
end.join(', ')
```